# "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `username` on serializer `UserSerializer`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

trying to get current user but it shows username keyerror but everything's all good from my side. Can anyone say whats the error?

views :

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def register(request):
data = request.data

user = SignUpSerializer(data=data)
if user.is_valid():

    if not User.objects.filter(username = data['email']).exists():

        user = User.objects.create(
            first_name = data['first_name'],
            last_name = data['last_name'],
            username = data['email'],
            email = data['email'],
            password = make_password(data['password'])
        )
        return Response({
            'details':'Sucessfully registered.'
        }, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response({
            'error':'User already exists.'
        }, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
else:
    return Response(user.errors)
```

here is UserSerializer views.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def current_user(request):
    user = UserSerializer(request.data)
    print(user)
    return Response(user.data)
```

Serializers.py :

```
class SignUpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')

    extra_kwargs = {
        'first_name':{'required':True, 'allow_blank':False},
        'last_name':{'required':True, 'allow_blank':False},
        'email':{'required':True, 'allow_blank':False},
        'password':{'required':True, 'allow_blank':False, 'min_length':4}
    }
```

This is user serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username')
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: `KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `username` on serializer `UserSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'username'."
`

Comment: Please include your traceback error as text.

Comment: Are you using a custom user model?

Comment: No, I'm using the default one provided

Comment: ```SignupSerializer``` doesn't have the ```username``` field.

Comment: In the view you provided only the sign up serializer is being used not the user serializer. Provide the view that uses the user serializer

Comment: Yes, but i'm not using SignUpSerializer, I'm using UserSerializer

Comment: Look i've provided my UserSerializers views

Comment: Ensure the payload has the username i.e. the request data

Comment: Can you explain more in detail i'm new still in learning stage.

Comment: You seem to be making a get request, hence no data is being passed in the request object. Do you want to get the logged in user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead. Replace request.data with request.user

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def current_user(request):
user = UserSerializer(request.user)
print(user)
return Response(user.data)
```

Comment: Whats the difference between adding .data instead of .user?

Comment: You use request.data mostly for posts requests i.e you are passing in data to the api to create or update. In your case, you want to get data from the api regarding the user. That user data is stored in the request.user. If you check request.data, it is blank

Comment: okay thanks man.